# Getting a constant distance between footnote and fancy footer

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, fancyhdr

How can I configure the distance between the two? There seem to be a lot of resources dealing with the distance between text and footnote, but not for footnote and footer. My document has multiple distances on different pages, but the minimal example I've produced doesn't (it is well-behaved). I would welcome suggestions on producing a better example, because I don't want to publish the entire document's source.

Look at the first and third image to see how their spacing differs. My document has both distances, on different pages.

[image: Full page]
[image: Spaced page]

Bad page from the document:

[image: Bad page from document]

Minimal code (well-behaved):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\lhead[eo]{}
\rhead[eo]{}
\chead[eo]{}
\lfoot[eo]{Footer}
\rfoot[eo]{Footer}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
    \kern -3pt
    \hrule width \textwidth height 0.5pt
    \kern 2pt%
}

\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm} % gap between text and footer
%\setlength{\footskip}{1.5cm}

\begin{document}

Text \footnote{footnote 1} \blindtext

\blindtext \footnote{footnote 2} 

\blindtext \footnote{footnote 3} \footnote{footnote 4}

\blindtext \footnote{footnote 5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using the `article` class, which by default uses `\raggedbottom`, you can load the `footmisc` package with the option `bottom`.

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

This (together with `\raggedbottom`) forces footnotes to the bottom of the page, so they have a constant distance from your fancy foot.

MWE (note that `footmisc` has to be loaded **before** `hyperref`):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\lhead[eo]{}
\rhead[eo]{}
\chead[eo]{}
\lfoot[eo]{Footer}
\rfoot[eo]{Footer}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
    \kern -3pt
    \hrule width \textwidth height 0.5pt
    \kern 2pt%
}

\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm} % gap between text and footer
%\setlength{\footskip}{1.5cm}

\begin{document}

Text \footnote{footnote 1} \blindtext

\blindtext \footnote{footnote 2}

\blindtext \footnote{footnote 3} \footnote{footnote 4}

\blindtext \footnote{footnote 5}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For posterity: By tweaking `\footskip` to 0.7cm I made it look symmetrical, and [here's the result](http://i.imgur.com/Ds5IYmD.png). I also modified `\footrulewidth` for appearance.

Comment: @DavidLord You're welcome.